# One linkedlist prints but the other nonempty linked list doesn't: Revised and expanded

Tags: java, printing, linked-list

I have revised this question. I have two linkedlists, one for each object type (Vertex, Edge).  The linkedlist of edges prints, but the linkedlist of vertices does not. This problem persists if I switch the order or separate the code into two methods.

Here is the print method

```
public void printList() {        
    ListIterator edgeIter = m_EdgeList.listIterator();
    Edge e;
    while (edgeIter.hasNext()) {
        e = (Edge)edgeIter.next();
        System.out.println(e.getName()+e.getOrientation());
    }
    ListIterator vertexIter = m_VertexList.listIterator();
    Vertex v;
    while (vertexIter.hasNext()) {
        v = (Vertex)vertexIter.next();
        System.out.println(v.getName()+":"+v.getIncidentEdge(1).getName()+ v.getIncidentEdge(1).getOrientation()+v.getIncidentEdge(2).getName()+ v.getIncidentEdge(2).getOrientation());
    }
}
```

The linkedlist is not empty.  As I create it I print the size and see that it increases.  Also, when I just print the raw list followed by a prefacing print of the size I get:

[com.expertdecision.topology.classification.structure.Vertex@de6ced, com.expertdecision.topology.classification.structure.Vertex@c17164, com.expertdecision.topology.classification.structure.Vertex@1fb8ee3]
Surface: f1: consisting of 3 vertices

It seems like the vertex iterator isn't working as expected, but I use it the same way as I use the edge iterator.

Here is the method that creates the linkdlist for the edges from an array of edges:

```
 public void setEdgeList(Edge[] edges) {
     String method = "setEdges(Edge[])";
     if (m_Tracing) Tracing.print(m_Class + "::" + method);
      m_EdgeList = new LinkedList<Edge>();
      ListIterator iter = m_EdgeList.listIterator();
      for (int i=0; i<m_EdgeCount; i++) {
            iter.add(edges[i]);
      }
  }
```

Here is the method that creates the linkedlist for the vertices:

```
 /**
 * Create vertices for every pair of edges
 */
public void createVertices() {
    String method = "createVertices()";
    if (m_Tracing) Tracing.print(m_Class + "::" + method);
    int iVertex;
    String[] vlabel = {"A","B","C","D","E","F","G"};
    //This implementation uses a LinkedList
    m_VertexList = new LinkedList<Surface>();   
    ListIterator eIter = m_EdgeList.listIterator();
    Vertex v;
    Edge e1;
    Edge e2;
    //
    iVertex = 0;    
    e1 = (Edge)eIter.next();        
   while (eIter.hasNext()) {
        e2 = (Edge)eIter.next();            
        v = new Vertex(vlabel[iVertex],e1, e2);
        if (m_Debugging) System.out.println("Adding " + v.getName()+ " to vertex list");
        m_VertexList.add(v);
        if (m_Debugging) System.out.println("Current size of vertex list is " +m_VertexList.size());
        iVertex++;
        e1 = e2;
    }
    //Vertex for the last-first edge    
    e2 = (Edge)m_EdgeList.get(0);
    v = new Vertex(vlabel[iVertex],e1, e2);
    if (m_Debugging) System.out.println("Adding " + v.getName()+ " to vertex list");
    m_VertexList.add(v);
    if (m_Debugging) System.out.println("Current size of vertex list is " +m_VertexList.size());
    if (m_Debugging) printList();
}
```

Comment: Is the `m_VertexList` empty?

Comment: @GáborBakos that seems to be the case.

Comment: Thanks, but the list is not empty--see revised question.

Comment: Can you show any code that does the instantiating of the edge and vertex objects? And maybe any other code interacting with them?

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, I have added the methods that create the two lists.

Answer (score 1):

Either use a debugger (like in Eclipse) or set some System.out lines to verify, but it seems the arraylist is empty and not entering the while-loop.

Comment: Thanks, but the list is not empty--see revised question.

Answer (score 0):

The first point is the answer you are looking for I hope, but the other parts are also interesting if that is not the case (sorry for not asking in comments).

1. You are getting the second point with the constant `2`, but probably you have only `0` and `1`. Arrays are indexed from `0` in Java.
2. Do you catch exceptions? (Your comment about changing the order does not affect the outcome suggests not, just want to be sure.) [Catching exceptions without at least printing out the stacktrace is very bad habit.]
3. In case the answer to first question yes... Any chance that the edge is `null`, or the
4. (Why do you use raw types?)
5. (Why do you need ListIterators?)
6. Can you share the implementation of `Vertex#getIncidentEdge(1)`?

So I would use something like this:

```
   System.out.println(v.getName()+":"+v.getIncidentEdge(0).getName()+ v.getIncidentEdge(0).getOrientation()+v.getIncidentEdge(1).getName()+ v.getIncidentEdge(1).getOrientation());
```

@Ascalonian's answer is a useful suggestion. With that, you could see the problem when you set a breakpoint to `Exception`. After that, you just have to examine the stack to see the problem.

Comment: I just came back on to report that I had found the problem just now (not with Lists!), and I see that Gabor has provided the answer in the meantime.  Indeed, it was the indexing using 1 and 2 instead of 0 and 1--very careless mistake but since I never used lists I blamed the lists!  Thanks very much to Gabor and Ascalonian--I really appreciate it.  And, I will follow their additional advice of starting to use try/catch blocks.